# "Gutheißen" vs "billigen": Unterschied und Bedeutung

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Ich würde gerne den Unterschied zwischen den beiden Verben "gutheißen" und "billigen" wissen, und ob es Situationen gibt, wo eines der Verben besser passt, als das andere.

Konkrete Beispiele, bei denen ich mir nicht sicher bin:

> Wenn meine Oma diesen Witz gehört hätte, würde sie ihn nicht billigen
> / gutheißen.
>
> Ich treffe solche Entscheidungen nicht, bevor es mein Chef billigt /
> gutheißt.
>
> Politische Regeln, die dort herrschen, heißt er nicht gut / missbilligt
> er.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Etwas zu billigen bedeutet, dass man das, was gebilligt wird, zwar akzeptiert, dass man darüber aber nicht unbedingt begeistert ist. In *billigen* steckt oftmals Widerwillen.

Wenn man etwas gutheißt, tut man das gerne. Man ist froh darüber.

> Erwin hieß den Vorschlag von Günther zwar nicht gut, billigte ihn aber ihrer Freundschaft willen.

Zu erwähnen ist aber auch, dass dieser Unterschied nicht sehr groß und nicht sehr stark ausgeprägt ist. Ich der überwiegenden Mehrzahl der Fälle sind die beiden Wörter austauschbar.

Comment: "In billigen steckt oftmals Widerwillen." Das hängt davon ab, was man unter oft versteht. Oft ist es auch neutral, etwa bei Institutionenhandeln: Die Verwaltung hat den Vorschlag gebilligt. Womöglich ist näheres zu deren Emotionen unbekannt und nur ein digitales Ergebnis bekannt, gebilligt, ja oder nein. Gutheißen kann man umgekehrt auch mit Bauchschmerzen, weil keine bessere Alternative da ist oder weil man aus formalen Gründen gezwungen ist - dann würde man aber in der Tat eher zu "billigen" greifen, wobei beide Begriffe oft :) reserviert daherkommen.

Comment: Hubert, vielen Dank für die Antwort!

Comment: Noch eine Frage hinterher: liegt das Verb "befürworten" eher in der nähe von "gutheißen" oder "billigen"? Beziehungsweise, gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesem Verb und den beiden aus meiner ursprünglichen Frage?

Comment: »Gutheißen« liegt zwischen »befürworten« und »billigen«. Mit »befürworten« wird also noch stärker als mit »gutheißen« ausgedrückt, dass man dafür ist, das zu tun. Wer etwas befürwortet, setzt sich mitunter auch aktiv für etwas ein. Wenn ein Verein gegründet wird, nennt man die Proponenten, die sich bei der Behörde mit ihrem Namen und ihrer Unterschrift für die Gründung einsetzen, auch »Befürworter«.

Comment: Hubert, danke noch mal!

Answer (score 3):

»Billigen« liegt in der Nähe von »dulden«, »gutheißen« in der Nähe von »loben«, der Unterschied ist also nicht unerheblich. Bei deinen Beispielen musst du daher abwägen, ob du eher von »[nicht] dulden« oder eher von »[nicht] loben« sprechen willst, austauschbar sind »billigen« und »gutheißen« nicht.

Davon abgesehen würde ich bei deinen ersten beiden Beispielen andere Verben verwenden (die in diesem Zusammenhang üblicher sind) und das dritte Beispiel anders beginnen lassen.

> Wenn meine Oma diesen Witz gehört hätte, würde sie ihn verurteilen.
>
> Ich treffe solche Entscheidungen nicht, bevor es mein Chef abgesegnet hat.
> (*Besser:* Ich treffe solche Entscheidungen nicht, bevor mein Chef sie abgesegnet hat.)
>
> Die politischen Regeln, die dort herrschen, heißt er nicht gut / billigt er nicht / missbilligt er.

Comment: Wieso "es" in Beispiel 2, Satz 1?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich habe das vom OP übernommen. Schön finde ich das nicht und kann auch nicht beurteilen, ob es falsch ist oder nicht, auch dann nicht, wenn ich den Satz umdrehe: _»Bevor es mein Chef abgesegnet hat, treffe ich solche Entscheidungen nicht.«_

Comment: Die Entscheidungen - "sie". In Satz 2 machst Du es doch auch. »Bevor sie mein Chef abgesegnet hat, treffe ich solche Entscheidungen nicht.« oder »Ich treffe solche Entscheidungen nicht, bevor sie mein Chef abgesegnet hat.«

Comment: @userunknown: Ich mache das, weil ich _»sie«_ in allen Fällen besser finde. Ich fürchte, dass _»es«_ nicht falsch wäre, nur schlechter. Nachweisen kann ich es, wie gesagt, nicht.

Comment: Inwiefern könnte "es" denn richtig sein? Worauf sollte es sich beziehen? Es kann sich nur auf ein sächliches Substantiv beziehen, aber wir haben keins. Also ist "es" falsch.

Comment: @userunknown: Wie gesagt, ich habe keinen Nachweis, ist nur ein Gefühl, das am stärksten ist, wenn der Satz umgedreht wird (mein erster Kommentar). _»Es«_ könnte sich auf die Handlungsweise / Handhabung (das Treffen solcher Entscheidungen) beziehen.

Comment: Pollitzer, vielen Dank für die Antwort und vor allem für das Eingehen auf meine Beispiele! (Ich muss an meinem Deutsch noch viel arbeiten :) Habe in dem zweiten Beispiel in der Tat mit "es" die Handlungsweise gemeint).

Comment: @Pollitzer: Ich wollte nochmal unterstreichen, dass das nicht geht, und kam beim Schreiben der Begründung auf die Idee, dass es doch gehen könnte. Ich bin aber noch unsicher und würde es selbst unterlassen, wenn es mir bewusst würde. Vielleicht wird es das aber nicht - kann ich ja schlecht sagen, solange es unbewusst ist. Mein Stolpern über den Satz lässt mich aber weiter zweifeln.